# numpy.fft.fft can not have 4 arguments?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I tried to do FFT with numpy using this:

```
    sp=np.fft.fft(np.exp(-t), 1000, -1, "ortho")
```

and it returns:

```
    TypeError: fft() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

But in the manual, numpy.fft.fft() is defined as:

```
    numpy.fft.fft(a, n=None, axis=-1, norm=None)
```

n, axis, and norm are optional, and norm can be set to "ortho". 
Why can't I use what I wrote?
Thanks.

Comment: what version of numpy do you have? `norm` is new to v1.10 so if you have an older version, there is no `norm` keyword.

Comment: What does `np.version.short_version` say?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786227/numpys-fft-with-intel-mkl

Answer (score 0):

What version of numpy are you using?

I ask because

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft

refers to norm as "New in version 1.10.0.", and if you were using an older version, the error message would be consistent with the behavior.